# Python requests not getting the right HTML

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to **scrape** a site to get an HTML  attribute. The problem is that it doesn't show up in the get request, but other attributes do!

for example:
In Chrome Inspect the HTML tag is like this

```
<input a="example", id="example_id", name="example_name", disabled="disabled"/>
```

But in my Python request is like this

```
<input a="example", id="example_id", name="example_name"/>
```

this is my code:

```py
page_raw = requests.get(WEBSITE_URL, headers=headers, timeout=10)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_raw.content, "html.parser")
print(page_soup.prettify())
print(page_soup.findAll("input", {"id":"example_id"}))
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: The DOM is most likely being modified by javascript, which is executed by a browser, hence **not** executed when scraping using `requests` and `beautofulsoup`. Consider using other scraping solutions that allow javascript execution, such as `selenium`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll give it a try!